# gulp-uglify causes constructor.name misbehaviour

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, gulp-uglify

In my gulpfile.js if I comment this line

```js
.pipe(uglify({ preserveComments: 'some'}))
```

then my code is not looking ugly and for following line of code everything is working fine.

```js
if(Mystudy.constructor.name != "MyStudyView")
```

but if I uglify my code using gulp-uglify(without commenting that uglify code on top)
then the above line looks something like this

```js
if ("MyStudyView" != e.constructor.name)
```

and value of e.constructor.name is also getting ugly like "e" instead of the "MyStudyView".

I want to run my code the same way as it was working without uglifying and I don't want to compromise on the uglify as well, is there any way that I can achieve what I want?

Extra information:
That "if" condition code is written in the filename of `mystudy.js` and under the function `closeIt`

Comment: Use [`if (Mystudy instanceof MyStudeView)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) instead, and you won't get bitten by uglification

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky Thaks for this suggestion. I tried this but again it is throwing an exception. Because there are some cases where we are not instantiating MyStudyView or that class not coming into the picture then it is throwing an exception of "MyStudyView is not defined" and for the same reason, I was using constructor.name.

Comment: There's `keep_fnames: true` [option in UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS#minify-options). Find how you can supply it to gulp-uglify

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky, Yes I tried keep_fnames and keep_classnames. But unfortunately, those also not worked for me. So I found something like mangle: property in which exclude can be used but I am not able to use it properly and I am not getting any proper documentation where it is properly getting explained like what parameters should be sent to that exclude array? is it function name, class name, or variable name, SO I stopped over there. And my ultimate goal was achieving this so directly put this question here.

Comment: @KedarGhadge If `keep_fnames` is not working for you, there is probably another issue with your minified code not related to constructor names.

Comment: @GOTO0 Yes actually keep_fnames created some more issues for me to solve and those were kinda more complex and unknown I was afraid that it may create more trouble in my code so I didn't give more try on it. And I was not sure about the keep_classnames I tried with it but it didn't work.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. `keep_fnames` brings the output _closer_ to the original code, with which you are comfortable (as you say). But now you are saying that it made things even worse. Clearly, there's an unrelated issue with the code, which means that there's not much we can help you with.

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky, Thanks I got an idea from your first suggestion. So, I checked first `if(typeof(MyStudyView)!='undefined')` before checking if it is an instance of so now it is working fine. If MyStuddyVIew is accessible then that 'if 'condition is returning true and then I am checking if it is an instance of.

Comment: Two things: 1) [`typeof` is not a function, it's an operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof), don't confuse it with [`typeof` compiler extension for C](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html), parentheses are not needed; 2) the syntax `undefined instance of SomeClass` won't throw errors, it will just return `false`, so not checking the type beforehand is also fine. Otherwise, I'm glad it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing

```js
if(Mystudy.constructor.name != "MyStudyView")
```

write

```js
if(Mystudy.constructor.name != MyStudyView.name)
```